# Building OpenSSL in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, openssl

i want to know how to build ssleay32 and libeay32 from vc++, were to get the source code,and how to build it.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL source is located [here](http://www.openssl.org/source/) and includes build files for VC++.
Your first information source is `INSTALL.W32` with a good instructions on how to compile the library. Also, you may check `README` file under `ms` directory.

After you're done with the lib compilation you should link the library to your project with OpenSSL specific code:

- Select Project
- Select Settings
- Select Link tab
- Select Input Category
- The libraries are listed here: "Object/library modules"
- If necessary additional paths can be added here: "Additional library paths

Comment: i want the library to be built along with my application.
so i need to include it in my project and have to build it.
please let meknw whether it i possible or not

Comment: and in INSTALL.w32 its givewn that we have to complie with cmd line and with perl only, is it necessary to do so

Comment: Why you need to build the library along with application? Just link it as the shared (dll) or static (should be possible) library or be ready that your project compilation will take a lot of time in case if you decide to put the OpenSSL sources directly into your project.

Comment: ya you are true, for some src maintaincec purpose i have to do it , so please atleast tell me how to complie openssl in vc6
as i dont find any project or workspave there in openssl downloaded folder